# How to store data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to store data to DB.
Following your recommendations, I created a schema

```php
Schema::create('user_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('name')->index();
      $table->string('ip');
      $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
});
```

I created a model for a UserInfo where I plan to store IP and name

```php
class UserInfo extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['ip']; 
}
```

In HomeController

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
   $user_info = new UserInfo;
   $user_info->ip = $request->ip;
   $user_info->name = $request->name;
   $user_info->save();
}
UserInfo::create(['user_info' => Request::user_info()]);
```

As a result, I've got the below-given error

> Method Illuminate\Http\Request::user_info does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request` is a class. Instead, use the `$request` variable provided as an argument in your function:

```
 UserInfo::create(['user_info' => $request->input('user_info')]);
```

Comment: Did you run your migration using proper credentials in .env file?

Comment: @sn n  I ran php artisan migrate:refresh. This added id table.

Comment: @Anders I opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047385/how-to-get-this-code-work-to-store-in-laravel-no-errors-and-no-storage

Comment: @Anders I guess your answer was the most concise considering the question. But I still can't get this code to work.

Answer (score 2):

Look there are several issues. Firstly in Schema consider using an incremental id as the primary key.

Add name in the `fillable` property.

```
protected $fillable = ['name','ip'];
```

And finally in the controller either use one procedure to save to the database.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $user_info = new UserInfo;

    $user_info->ip = $request->ip;
    $user_info->name = $request->name;
    $user_info->save();
}
```

Or

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    UserInfo::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'ip'   => $request->ip
    ]);
}
```

Comment: fillable attributes don't matter because OP is not doing mass assignment

Comment: The error went away but still nothing new in DB. I did what you suggested except for id. How should I declare it?

Comment: @Caddy DZ  I added a field   $table->increments('id'); The result is the same.

Comment: @Brad_Fresh how are you trying to insert in DB??

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon When user logged in, I got his IP and name and then pass in to DB(in HomeController)

Comment: `dd($request)` to check if you get the values. and which one of the above insert process you are using??

Comment: @ zahid hasan emon  Sorry. Haven't noticed your comment. I use UserInfo::create(['name'=> $request->input('name'),'ip'=>$request->input('ip')]); I opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047385/how-to-get-this-code-work-to-store-in-laravel-no-errors-and-no-storage?noredirect=1#comment102496957_58047385