# How to get this code work to store in Laravel. No errors and no storage

Tags: database, laravel

I can't store name and IP address to DB. I created a table 'info' with appropriate fields by running php artisan migrate.

A schema

```
 Schema::create('info', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('ip');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
 });
```

A model for Info

```
class Info extends Model
  {
   protected $fillable = ['ip', 'name']; 
  }
```

Maybe the problem is in my HomeController where I get those variables?

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use App\Info;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 use Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
  {
     public function __construct()
   {
    $this->middleware('auth');
   }

public function store(Request $request) {
    Info::create(['info' => $request->input('info')]);
}


public function index()
  {
    if (Auth::check())
  {
    $name = Auth::user()->name;
    $ip = Request::ip();

  \App\Events\eventIp::dispatch($ip,$name);
  return view('home');
  }
 }
}
```

My routes in web.php

```
Route::post('/home','HomeController@store');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

});

But it doesn't work. Gives no errors and no records in DB.

Something make me think that it have to do with my index function. I got info in function index and maybe function store doesn't have a clue what I mean.

Comment: How do you call your route? (Form, postman, etc)

Comment: @mdexp In web.php I have Route::post('/home','HomeController@store'); In HomeController(home.blade.php) I get IP and name . Then I would like to store it to DB.

Comment: I meant how do you actually execute that route? Do you use postman to make a POST http call?

Comment: @mdexp no, I didn't

Comment: @mdexp  What it would look like?

Comment: Do you have a form in the home view? If so can you post that one as well?

Comment: @mdexp Well, if I don't have api?

Comment: @mdexp I don't have a form. I get this information from  Auth and Request(see above in the question).

Comment: @mdexp I think I get what you talking about. I ran php artisan make:auth and I have a login page with a form. Do I have to point my Route::post to my login page? But when I did this, it refreshed my page(form fields) and still nothing in DB.

Comment: @mdexp I added my routes in the question.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: are you trying to register ip and name of the logged in user to the database each time it visit the `/home` route after login?

Comment: @mdexp You are absolutely correct! This is the task I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller action is basically a method that usually gets executed when you open an url (as you connect them to routes).

In your example you have connected two routes to their respective actions:

```php
Route::post('/home','HomeController@store');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Now, when you log in succesfully, imagine that you end up in the page with url `http://localhost:8000/home` in your web browser.

The key difference is the method which you use to call your route (you can get an overview of the differences [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)), in your case you are using GET method.

The resulting action executed it the one associated to `/home` route with the GET method, that is the `HomeController@index` action (or method).

The store method, although is in the same HomeController class, doesn't get triggered unless you execute the `/home` route, but **with the POST method**.

You can confirm that if you put a debug message in each of the methods like this:

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        echo 'I will not be executed';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'I have been executed';
    }
}
```

If you want to simply save a info record when you visit the `/home` route with the GET method, you can put the save in the index method itself and get rid of the store method:

```php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // You can omit Auth::check() because you are using the auth middleware
        // that exactly does this job.
        Info::create([
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'ip' => Request::ip(),
        ]);

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that doing in this way you will get a new database record for each page view you make to that route (if you keep refreshing the page, you should see new records being added to database).

#### Update

When you use Eloquent Models, laravel will look for a table named after the pluralized model name (`Info` model will try to use `infos` table).

However you created a table named `info`. To solve that you can either rename the table and rerun the migration with `php artisan migrate:refresh` (**it will delete all the existing data in the database you are using for your laravel app**)

Or specify the table name to use for that laravel model:

```php
class Info extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'info';
    protected $fillable = ['ip', 'name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did the actions above. Now I have an error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist.

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve that issue, let me know if that works!

Comment: It worked!  Wow, what a ride! You did your best with explanation and helping advices.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the functions? There is a couple of things wrong with your code, but you're saying there are no errors at all.

Firstly, your `Info::create` call does not need the `['info' => $request->input('info')]` info. This is because your Info model has no database property called `info`, but normally you would get an obvious error with the approach, which is why I expect you are also calling the store method incorrectly.

Call the create method like so:

`$infoModel = Info::create(['name' => $request->input('name'), 'ip' => $request->input['ip']]);`

or, if you can guarantee your `$request` only contains the needed fields (properly validated), you can just do

`$infoModel = Info::create($request->all());`

Add a little more info to the question on how you are calling `store` and we can probably solve the rest of your problem.

Comment: Well, that's all I have. I call this in web.php Route::post('/','HomeController@store');

Comment: Are you sure about input('name')? I thought we use this when getting information from the form input.

Comment: I quess the proper question would be how to call this function.

Comment: Well, you appear to be calling "store" correctly. The input("name") is what is used to pull the "name" data from the form submit, but you still need to apply it to a database field on the 'Info" object. In your case, both the form field and the database field have the same name (hence, why we can use the shorter version), but using the longer version may help you understand it better.

Comment: I tried code you wrote but still, nothing happens. No errors though.

Answer (score 0):

Within your store function inside HomeController  , use

```
Info::create([
            'name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'ip' => Request::ip(),
        ]);
```

and make sure Info model is imported.
Also make sure your route has the call to store function while POSTing data .